# MySQL equivalent session variable for Oracle

Tags: mysql, oracle, plsql, session-variables

In MySQL, I can create an access a session variable by using a single @.
Example initialization:

```
set @myVar = true;
```

Some trigger containing this code:

```
if (@myVar is not true) then
  execute something
```

What is the equivalent in Oracle 10g?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
SQL> EXEC DBMS_SESSION.SET_CONTEXT('CLIENTCONTEXT', 'myvar', 'myvalue');

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed

SQL> SELECT SYS_CONTEXT('CLIENTCONTEXT', 'myvar') FROM dual;

SYS_CONTEXT('CLIENTCONTEXT','M
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
myvalue
```

Answer (score 2):

A package global variable would probably do the same trick.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE foo as
  myVar BOOLEAN;
END foo;


CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY foo AS
  BEGIN
    MyVar := true;
END foo;


BEGIN
  If foo.myVar THEN 
    dbms_output.put_line ('MyVar is True');
  end if;
END;
```

An advantage of using the package over SYS_CONTEXT is that you get some encapsulation.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just use bind variables? In SQL Plus:

```
variable SOME_NUMBER number
exec :SOME_NUMBER := 10
```

> PL/SQL procedure successfully completed

```
if :SOME_NUMBER = 10 then
   do something;
end if;
/
```

Works for any kind of Oracle datatype.

Comment: the variable needs to be accessible from outside the PL\SQL in a trigger elsewhere.